# Java EE @ApplicationScoped vs Singleton Pattern

Tags: jakarta-ee

I need a **utility class** which only has to generate a relatively complex file from a given input. The input differs, the process of generating the file is always the same.

Now the question:
Would it be better to use an **@ApplicationScoped** bean or just a class using the **Singleton Pattern** and work with static methods?

As far as i know both classes are only instatiated once per JVM and also kept in memory only once. I do not need an inject, the singleton would work fine. Are there any advantages for my performance or the memory usage using one of the listed possibilites?

Comment: Did you look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555844/what-is-the-difference-between-applicationscoped-and-singleton-scopes-in-cdi

Comment: yes i did, i am not talking about the @Singleton annotation, i am talking about the pattern: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/singleton_pattern.htm