# jboss-as 7 class loading within a war with ApplicationScoped eager ManagedBean

Tags: jsf, classloader, managed-bean, jboss7.x

I have this kind of structure in my Maven project:

```
WEB-INF/lib
  - a.jar
       - Registry.class (@ApplicationScoped, @ManagedBean(eager=true)
  - b.jar
       - Module.class (@ApplicationScoped, @ManagedBean(eager=true)
```

I placed a logger at the @PostConstruct annotated method on the two classes to determine which is invoked first and after several deployments on the JBossAS7 server, I noticed that **there SEEMS to be no specific order in loading** these classes. My intention is to ALWAYS have Registry.class loaded before Module.class. But with this class loading behavior, I don't know how to achieve it.

In some instances, Registry.class is being loaded first but in other instances, Module.class gets loaded first **even if I just restarted the application server and did no changes on the code**.

Now my question is, is there something that I can do to define the order of loading jars within the WEB-INF/lib?

---

A different perspective:

Can it also be possible that the problem is not within the class loading but with the ApplicationScoped eager ManagedBean? I added a class on a.jar:

```
- RegistryTwo.class (@ApplicationScoped, @ManagedBean(eager=true)
```

so that **a.jar** now contains Registry.class and RegistryTwo.class. With this, I am expecting something like:

(**Desired output**)

```
Registry.class is invoked.
RegistryTwo.class is invoked.
Module.class is invoked.
```

or (I have will have a problem with this.)

```
Module.class is invoked.
Registry.class is invoked.
RegistryTwo.class is invoked.
```

**BUT** in some instances, I am getting this:

```
RegistryTwo.class is invoked.
Module.class is invoked.

... (Other Processing logs.)

Registry.class is invoked.
```

According to @BalusC, an ApplicationScoped eager ManagedBean will be auto-instantiated upon application startup (
[How do I force an application-scoped bean to instantiate at application startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600534/jsf-how-do-i-force-an-application-scoped-bean-to-instantiate-at-application-st)) and that happens in my code.

I just wonder:

1. How does JSF load/create ApplicationScoped eager ManagedBeans? Is there some sort of rule wherein the order is/can be defined?
2. Why was Registry.class not instantiated before/right after RegistryTwo.class when they are both under the same jar file and they are both ApplicationScoped?

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no ordering rule.

I suggest to let `Registry` implement [`ServletContextListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) or maybe [`ServletContainerInitializer`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.html) instead. Both are guaranteed to run before before JSF application scoped bean constructions.

In case of `ServletContextListener`, you could let `Registry` put itself in the application scope as follows:

```
@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
    event.getServletContext().setAttribute("registry", this);
}
```

It'll be available in JSF/EL the usual way by `#{registry}`.