# Differences : @SessionScoped vs @Stateful and @ApplicationScoped vs @Singleton

Tags: java, singleton, ejb, stateless, stateful

I would like to know, what are the **principal differences** between :

1. [javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/context/SessionScoped.html) and [javax.ejb.Stateful](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/Stateful.html)
2. javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped and javax.ejb.Singleton

I know that a *@SessionScoped* and a *@Stateful* allows to create a new instance for each client. I also know that for the *@ApplicationScoped* and *@Singleton / @Stateless* they are shared between the clients.

=> But **when should I consider** it's better to choose an EJB, or the other?

Answer (score 32):

`@SessionScoped` denotes a scope while `@Stateful` is in a way what we would now call a stereotype. `@Stateful` adds a number a services to a bean, among which transactional behavior and passivation.

Central to `@Stateful` is however its session behavior, which indeed overlaps with the session scope.

The difference is that the session scope is tied to the HTTP session, while `@Stateful` is an open-ended user managed session, with its lifetime managed by a client that has a reference to the bean proxy.

`@Stateful` remote beans were originally the binary (RMI) counter parts of Servlets. Where Servlets listened to remote HTTP requests from a browser, `@Stateful` remote beans listened to remote RMI requests from Applets (and later Swing clients).

There were unfortunately many inconsistencies between the two. A Servlet was just an HTTP listener, while `@Stateful` beans automatically brought in a lot of other features. A Servlet also shared the session with all other Servlets and also shared the Java EE component namespace with all other Servlets in a war, while with the `@Stateful` EJB every separate bean has its own session and component namespace.

With the introduction of local beans in EJB 2 and a sharp decline of Swing/Applet clients for remote EJB communication, the function of the session that's maintained for an `@Stateful` bean has become less clear.

I think it's fair to say that `@Stateful` simply isn't used that much these days. For a web application the HTTP session is almost always leading, which means using the session scope and local `@Stateless` beans and/or CDI beans for business logic.

In some cases `@Stateful` beans are needed for their natural support for the extended persistence context from JPA and for their passivation features (Servlet doesn't have a standardized passivation mechanism). Note that `@Stateful` and `@SessionScoped` (or many other scopes) can be combined. The advantage of combining them is that user code no longer needs to manage the lifetime, but the container manages this.

There's a somewhat similar story for `@ApplicationScoped` and `@Singleton`, although without the legacy (`@Singleton` is a fairly new thing). `@ApplicationScoped` is just a scope, while `@Singleton` is a bean type (stereotype if you wish), which doesn't only give you application scoped behavior, but also provides you with transactional behavior again, with automatic locking (which can be tuned via `@Lock`) and with eager construction behavior (via `@Startup`).

Although `@Stateful` and `@Singleton` are by themselves pretty handy, the current way forward in Java EE seems to be to decompose those build-in stereotypes into separately useable annotations and who knows, perhaps one day they will be actual CDI stereotypes consisting of those decomposed annotations.

Comment: awesome.  can you provide links or further reading for some terminology?  passivation and stereotypes, specifically.

Comment: about stereotypes you can read in CDI manual